# Appending values to colors in leaflet heatmap according to different conditions

Tags: javascript, leaflet, heatmap

I've just started to learn leaflet Heatmap and I want to map values to different colors based on the conditions.

I'm getting list of datapoints(x, y, values) in a variable addresspoints through an ajax call and I want to map those values in such a way that, each color has a range and according to that the values fall in to that range and gets appended to the color.

I've read about the *fillColor:* attribute using the geoJSON object. But, I don't know how to implement that in leaflet heatmap as there's no *fillColor* attribute in the doc.

Also, what changes can be seen by varying the values of *max* attribute in heatmap.

```js
function initializeMap(x, y) {
  map.setView([ y / 2, x / 2 ], 0);
  loadmap(x, y);
  // map.setZoom(-3);
  // map.panTo(0,0);

  prevZoom = map.getZoom();

 }

 function loadmap(x, y) {
  var imgDimensions = {
   width : x,
   height : y
  };
    
  var num;
  var imageBounds = [ [ imgDimensions.height, 0 ],
    [ 0, imgDimensions.width ] ];

  L.imageOverlay(imageUrl, imageBounds).addTo(map);

  /*
   * L.tileLayer.zoomify(imageUrl,{ width: 5472, height: 3648, tolerance:
   * 0.8, attribution: 'Photo: Keerthi' }).addTo(map);
   * 
   * /*L.tileLayer.zoomify('http://thematicmapping.org/playground/zoomify/books/', {
   * width: 5472, height: 3648, tolerance: 0.8, attribution: 'Photo:
   * BjÃ¸rn Sandvik' }).addTo(map);
   */

  hr = height / imgDimensions.height;
  wr = width / imgDimensions.width;

  // Hardcoded

  // addressPoints = [ [ 100, 100, 1 ], [ 100, 50, 0.5 ] ];
  console.log(addressPoints);
  addressPoints = addressPoints.map(function(p) {
   p0 = p[0] / wr;
   p1 = p[1] / hr;
   var latlong = map.layerPointToLatLng(L.point(p0, p1));

   return [ latlong.lat, latlong.lng, p[2] ];
  });

  // Leaflet-heat Plug-in Code..
   
  heat = L.heatLayer(addressPoints, {
   // minOpacity : 1.0,
   max : 50,
   maxZoom : -3,
   // scale_dimming: 1.5,

   radius : rad,

   // radius_scale: 2,
   // zoom_scale : 25,
   // radius: 100,
   gradient : {
    '0.1' : '#80FF00',
    '0.2' : '#74DF00',
    '0.3' : '#00ff00',
    '0.4' : '#FFBF00',
    '0.5' : '#DBA901',
    '0.6' : '#DF3A01',
    '0.7' : '#B40404',
    '0.8' : '#8A0808',
    '0.9' : '#610B0B',
    '1.0' : '#3B0B0B'
   }
  });
  map.addLayer(heat);
```

Comment: did you see the official tutorial for Choropleth implementation ? http://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth/

Comment: @AlexParij In Choropleth implementation, they're passing geoJson object and I don't know how to convert my addresspoints to that.

Comment: Hey man, I'm stuck on exactly same question. Have you found the solution?